# How to hold the value in source variable while changing in destination (grid store)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some data in like this.

```
var myData = [{"name" : "David", "Country":"India"},{"name" : "Paul", "Country":"USA"}]
```

in my extJS grid I am loading data like this :

```
_this.getView().getStore().loadData(myData);
```

This is my editable grid. Now when I change the data in extJS grid ex : "country : USA" to "Country : England", How it will get update in myData Variable as well. How can do the copy of myData as store which change the value at both the places.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = [{"name" : "David", "Country":"India"},{"name" : "Paul", "Country":"USA"}];

_this.getView().getStore().loadData(Ext.Array.clone(myData));
```

The clone method will clone your myData variable and return a new Array.

[Clone method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.Array.html#method-clone)

Comment: so, by doing this any data I change will refrect in `myData` my source data .

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. So you want the variable to always be the same when the values in the store changes?

Comment: yeah, correct. If I copy the it should always there works as js copy

Comment: I'm not sure about this since the Array items will be cast into model instances. But regarding your problem: If you need the current dataset after an update couldn't you use the 'datachanged' event on the store and get the current data via the getData method?